# Does express-openid-connect have typescript support?

Tags: typescript, express

I'm just wondering if there's documentation for how to use express-openid-connect in typescript, or whether there's support for it at all?

Answer (score 0):

`express-openid-connect` does come with type declarations out of the box, but you might have to additionally install declarations from dependencies, such as `@types/oidc-client` to get full support (e.g. when configuring `AuthorizationParameters`).

The TypeScript support is not perfect though. For example: currently there are no declarations for `request.oidc` or `response.oidc`, or `express-session` stores have an incompatible interface to `express-openid-connect`'s `ConfigParams.session.store`.

Such issues can usually be circumvented by casting to `any`, or not using dot notation (and overriding linting errors)

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/dot-notation
req['oidc'].isAuthenticated() ? …
```